# mysql query not working in this script

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

```
$host     = 'localhost';
$user     = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'egov';

$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die('Server Information is not Correct');
mysql_select_db($database, $conn) or die('Database Information is not correct');

$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'upload'(
file_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
fName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
lName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Mo INT(11) NOT NULL,
dese VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
file_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(file_id))ENGINE = MYISAM";

if (isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0) {
    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);

    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    }

    $da = date("dmy");
    echo $da;

    $fname = $_REQUEST['lastname'];
    $lname = $_REQUEST['firstname'];
    $pno   = $_REQUEST['mbo'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $query = $_REQUEST['description'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO upload (
                    fName,
                    lName,
                    Mo,
                    dese,
                    Email                   
                )
                VALUES (
                    '$fname',
                    '$lname',
                    '$pno',
                    '$email',
                    '$query ',
                    'file_name',
                    NOW()
                )";
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM upload";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";

    while( ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['fName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['lName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Mo']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['dese']."</td>";

    echo "<td>".$row['Email']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
```

The data is not inserting into table, I already asked it but got no reply. Don't down vote cause it'll ruin my account.

My html code is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
<input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile">
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What errors are you getting?

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Is that really all of your `html`?

Comment: no in first time wen it run on a server

Comment: The only query that I can see *actually being run* is the SELECT at the bottom. Maybe you should actually run the INSERT query?

Comment: 7 values inserted into 5 columns; but you're never actually executing the insert query, so no wonder it isn't working

Comment: @chriz: not exactly but from there am getting the uploading file

Comment: @Mark Baker: no 7 first am only inserting five values without file

Comment: Also make sure you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form.

Comment: @mukhesh except all of your columns are `NOT NULL` and have no default value, so if you do not specify a value for them the INSERT will fail, especially your primary key column.

Comment: @mukhesh - your $sql lists 5 column names, but has 7 values... if this isn't your real code, then show the real code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have following errors in your code:

1 - Remove single quotes from Create table query i.e

Change from

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  'upload'(file_id INT(11) NOT NULL,fName VARCHAR(255)    
NOT NULL,lName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,Mo INT(11) NOT NULL,dese VARCHAR(255) NOT 
NULL,Email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,file_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,PRIMARY 
KEY(file_id))ENGINE = MYISAM";
```

To

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  upload (file_id INT(11) NOT NULL,fName VARCHAR(255)    
NOT NULL,lName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,Mo INT(11) NOT NULL,dese VARCHAR(255) NOT 
NULL,Email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,file_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,PRIMARY 
KEY(file_id))ENGINE = MYISAM";
```

2 - Your insert query is wrong.

Number of values is more than the number of arguments i.e.

$sql = "INSERT INTO upload (
                    fName,
                    lName,
                    Mo,
                    dese,
                    Email
                )
                VALUES (
                    '$fname',
                    '$lname',
                    '$pno',
                    '$email',
                    '$query ',
                    'file_name',
                    NOW()
                )";
For 5 columns, you are giving 7 columns. Change the query like,

```
  INSERT INTO upload (
                fName,
                lName,
                Mo,
                dese,
                Email                   
            ) ....
```

To

```
INSERT INTO upload (
                fName,
                lName,
                Mo,
                dese,
                Email,
               NAME_OF_YOUR_QUERY_COLUMN,
               NAME_OF_YOUR_file_name_COLUMN,
               NAME_OF_YOUR_CURRENT_DATE_COLUMN
            ) ....
```

Comment: sorry NAME_OF_YOUR_CURRENT_DATE_COLUMN where can i get that

Comment: this is your column name in the "upload" table. Have you used MS Excel? its like column name! you need to spend some time with the basics of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `INSERT` statement (which you're never executing).

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO upload (
                fName,
                lName,
                Mo,
                dese,
                Email                   
            )
            VALUES (
                '$fname',
                '$lname',
                '$pno',
                '$email',
                '$query ',
                'file_name',
                NOW()
            )";
```

Your column list has 5 columns, and you're sending 7.

As mentioned in the comments, you should stop using `mysql_` functions and use prepared statements.

Comment: please can u giv me the prepared statement for this code plz.....

Comment: @mukhesh Ahh no. Please [read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement won't work (even if you executed it) because you don't add the `file_id` which is set to `NOT NULL` and is your primary key and as mentioned you pass more values than fields mentioned. So I'd start with changing the create table to this:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  'upload'(file_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,...
```

If you don't want to explicitly name the `file_id`, and then go and look at some more tutorials, there's plenty of them on the web. And read them carefully.

Answer (score 0):

First you are not executing you query using  `mysql_query($sql)`
and

secondly your count of your columns and the values you are sending for insert are not same ... 
This will generate the mysql error